# What kind of chip is used in my circuit board?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit

I have a toy car with buttons that produces sounds and music. It stopped working and I decided to try fixing it. There is a board with a chip. I used a multimeter to test voltage where the load speaker is connected when any button is pressed. It was always zero. I checked the load speaker and it works. I checked the inputs to the chip and they are good - I can see voltage changes when a button is pressed. So, my conclusion is that the chip is dead. Can you help me to figure out what kind of chip is this?  Below are the images of the board:
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's (probably) unnamed, unreleased bare silicon die encased under that blob of black epoxy, and it doesn't really matter what it is, because if it's broken there's no way you're going to repair it.

Comment: Some wires seem to have cold solder joints, you can try to resolder them, which might fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's some kind of an unknown dedicated toy Asian ASIC underneath that black epoxy blob. It is absolutely not reasonably repairable unless the problem is external to the blob. The construction is called Chip-On-Board (COB).

Look for lifted pads on that paper-based phenolic board or bad solder joints, especially on the flat cable. Try pushing or wiggling the leads, wires etc. and see if you can see any movement on the pads or protruding leads. Also clean the board with a toothbrush and 99% isopropanol - or failing that, at least hot water and detergent and let the board dry thoroughly- it appears to have gotten wet in the left lower corner.

If you can't find anything visible it's unlikely it's repairable, with the symptoms you describe.

Comment: By chip on board, do you mean that there's a bare, uncased chip inside those blobs when you see them?  So no markings even if you remove the blob somehow?

Comment: There might be microscopic markings on the die but it is a bare die with wire bonds [directly to the board](https://i.imgur.com/Mv8cW7D.jpg) (hence the nickel plate). And those markings, if present, will 99.99% be useless .

Comment: Good to know.  I've always seen those blobs as insurmountable but it never occurred to me they could actually be the chip casing.  Thanks Spehro.

Comment: The die will also be attached with epoxy to the PCB. Fine wire interconnects between metalized pads on the die and metal pads on the PCB. Then the whole lot is covered with epoxy. Totally not reworkable.